# System.Reactive choosing between Scheduler.Default and TaskPoolScheduler.Default

Tags: .net-core, system.reactive

I'm having significant difficulty choosing between `Scheduler.Default` and `TaskPoolScheduler.Default`.

I've seen it suggested that the TaskPoolScheduler is more efficient/optimised and it certainly has the benefit of being more explicit/specific; however, that doesn't help me understand the real differences, given that functionally they appear to do the same thing.

When is `Scheduler.Default` preferable to `TaskPoolScheduler.Default` and vice versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Scheduler.Default` is the same as `DefaultScheduler.Instance`.

How does the `DefaultScheduler` handle thunks? `DefaultScheduler` sits on top of a platform abstraction layer that schedules work depending on what system it's on.

This used to be the `System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll` assembly, which would differ according to the plaform, but for 4.x it's just an empty facade assembly to stay compatible with 3.x, with the implementation moved to `System.Reactive.dll`.

For DefaultScheduler:

- As of now, for scheduling immediate work, the `ThreadPool` is used.
- For periodic events (`SchedulePeriodic`) a `System.Threading.Timer` is used.
- For work which runs as fast as possible, a new thread is used.

The details of what platform service is chosen is in the [EnlightenmentProvider](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Internal/CurrentPlatformEnlightenmentProvider.cs).

You could maybe use `DefaultScheduler` when you have long-running computations or periodic events where TimeSpan is very small, or zero, although `EventLoopScheduler` may be better.

Prefer `TaskPoolScheduler` when possible. It's a lightweight implementation intended for short computations.